# Kendo UI Auto Complete displaying undefined

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, undefined, kendo-autocomplete

Trying to work with the Telerik Kendo UI MVC AutoComplete control.  I'm using server side filtering which works.  The results are coming back in the controller method, but I'm seeing 'Undefined' in the list of choice on the view.  The MVC details are below.

View

```
 @model List<USFS.Lending.LoanApprovalConditionSetup>

 @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
  .Name("Conditions")
  .DataTextField("ConditionName")
  .BindTo(Model)
  .MinLength(3)
  .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
  .Placeholder("Conditions Search...")
  .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("SearchLoanConditions", "LoanCondition")
            .Data("onConditionsSearch");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })

  )

 <script>
    function onConditionsSearch() {
        return {
            searchText: $("#Conditions").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult SearchLoanConditions(string searchText)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            searchText = String.Empty;
        }
        IEnumerable<LoanApprovalConditionSetup> loanConditions = SearchConditions(searchText);

        return PartialView("_searchConditions", loanConditions.ToList());
    }
```

Model
    My model is a standard class with properties in it.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Jim

Comment: What does the LoanApprovalConditionSetup class look like ?

Comment: It's a standard C# POCO class with properties.

Comment: Yeah, what are those properties ? Generally if your dropdown/autocomplete whatever is saying undefined on each item, it means your DataTextField is incorrect.

Comment: Robin is right.. the problem its you are not matching the dataTextField or the dataValueField properly

Comment: show us the properties of the LoanApprovalConditionSetup